# Difficulties creating pacman collision detection in C++

Tags: c++, game-physics, sfml

I am trying to make a pac game. I am using C++ and sfml. Everything looks fine for now, but the problem is that I don't have an idea how to make the map collision detection. I am loading the map from .bmp file. Here is a picture:

[image]

Is there a way to set wall cordinates so I could detect them on a collision ?

Here is a part of my code:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(451, 500), "Packman", sf::Style::Close);
    sf::Image icon;
    icon.loadFromFile("pac_icon.png");

    window.setIcon(icon.getSize().x, icon.getSize().y, icon.getPixelsPtr());

    sf::Texture tMap;
    tMap.loadFromFile("pac_map.bmp");
    sf::Sprite sprMap;
    sprMap.setTexture(tMap);

    Pac oPac(window);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed) 
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }   

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right) 
            && !(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)))
        {
            oPac.MoveRight();
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left) 
            && !(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)))
        {
            oPac.MoveLeft();
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
        {
            oPac.MoveUp();
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
        {
            oPac.MoveDown();
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }


        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprMap);
        oPac.Update();
        window.display();
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way with your current code you can get the location of pacman on the window?

Comment: @ejderuby yes, I can get and set every object's possition, colour, etc.

Comment: Define *"collision"*. Once done, you have your algorithm. What's left is to translate that into code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to **divide your world into cells**.

Every elements of your game can be placed into a tile (2D array of boolean for example, true is `there is an element` and false is `there is no element`).

Your character will be able to change its direction with your controls, and its position x and y will be modified over time depending on its direction.

You'll have to make an **algorithm that checks if a tile is reachable from another tile given a direction**. Thus, you'll be able to move your character in a direction and stops him when he can't reach a tile (Which is basically a collision detection + solving a collision).

If you want to learn about 2D collisions, here is a great article that treats **2D tilemap collision**: https://jonathanwhiting.com/tutorial/collision/.

Example of tilemap stored into a 2D array:

```
bool world[5][5] =
{
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
};

std::pair<int> playerPosition { 1, 1 };
```

Of course, you can load these information from a file. You can imagine a very basic data formatting:

```
11111
10001
10101
10001
11111
```

A `getline()` call + a char by char parsing for each line would do the job to parse this file

***Pro tip***: You can also write your level information in one line, assuming that every 5 chars you treat another line (height of your level) (Depending on your level width). It will reduce the parsing time and will also reduce your level file size (Ex: `1111110001101011000111111`)

***Pro tip 2***: You can encode your level data into integers or hexadecimals, thus, when you'll parse your file you'll need to convert these values into an arrays of booleans (Every boolean value will be determined by one bit of the integer/hexadecimal). `127[decimal]` can be represented as `‭01111111‬[binary]`, thus you can write more information with less characters, but you'll have to seperate your integers with some ',' (Ex: `31,17,21,17,31` to keep the same map as previous examples)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with sfml, but I can think of three general ways to do collision detection for something like this:

1. Sum all the pixels of the level/background that are within the bounding box of the pacman character. If the sum is 0, then all the pixels are black and there are no collision. But if the sum is greater than 0, then there are blue pixels in there and you have run into a wall. Of course, this is not exactly the fastest method.
2. Draw a second map like this: [image: Permission area] Then test the center pixel of pacman against that map: If the pixel is white, then you are ok. If it is not, then you have a collision. Plus, if it is easier to test against one of the corners of pacman, then just shift the white areas along the correct diagonal when you create the map.
3. Draw bounding boxes around all the walls of the map: [image: Bounding boxes], then store the xy-coordinates of those boxes in some data structure, and do box-box collision detection between them and the pacman box. This is more math heavy method, but the bounding box data should take up less memory than storing a full secondary bitmap (even if those maps can be 1-bit black and white).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful !

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to represent the walls in your program with coordinates, which you compare to the pacman.

I guess you could generate the walls from the image you provide but is probably the most difficult attempt.

I would suggest two solutions :
 - Either keep your image, and also store the coordinates and sizes of a set of rectangles that represent all the walls, and load both files when loading your level
 - You could instead of loading an image, store a representation of your level in a file, load that and then build the level (logic and graphics) from that.

Another alternative could pixel perfect collision but I don't know much about that.